# documentclient put is not working, tried everything

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

My hashkey is a number with the name pid

Here is the code

```
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {

var params = {
  TableName:"passengers",
  Item: {
    "pid": 55
  }
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("errrrrrrr");
    console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  } else {
    console.log("succccccc");
    console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
});
console.log("Added a new item...");

res.send('<h1>some html</h1>');


})
```

Neither errrr or succcc gets printed in the logs but both "Adding a new item" and "Added a new item" get printed.

Comment: `docClient.put()` is asynchrous, so `console.log("Added a new item...");` would be logged immediately, regardless.  That and `res.send(...` should be inside `else { ...`.

Comment: Thank you my man , I was going to go mad

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the `put` API is asynchronous. So, you should return the response to client when the put is successful or failed.

Please include the `res.send` inside the call back method. Alos, please use HttpMethod **POST** for putting the item rather than **GET** method. I hope you have just used it for quick testing purpose.

```
console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("errrrrrrr");
    console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    res.send('<h1>some error html</h1>');
  } else {
    console.log("succccccc");
    console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    res.send('<h1>some html</h1>');
  }
});
```

Comment: yeah that was for testing purposes, thanks for the reply